# Paste from system mac osx clipboard into terminal

Tags: python, macos, shell, terminal, markdown

I'm trying to use python-markdown to convert the system clipboard contents into HTML by running a shell script after pressing a hotkey and sending the processed markdown to `pbcopy`. The following is the shell script to make this happen.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo `pbpaste` | python -m markdown | pbcopy
```

The issue already known is that `pbpaste` will not contain the systems clipboard contents. Is there a similar utility to `pbpaste` that stores the clipboard contents?

Comment: Why can't you just run "pbpaste | python -m markdown | pbcopy"?

Comment: pbpaste contains the output from pbcopy, but I'm copying from cmd-c so it's not stored in pbpaste.

Comment: Interesting. At least on 10.6+, that doesn't seem to be the case. Note that there are different pasteboards -- did you alias pbpaste in your bashrc or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pbpaste` should work for this. You can even specify the general clipboard to ensure you're getting the main system clipboard.

```
#!/bin/sh

pbpaste -pboard general | python -m markdown | pbcopy
```